# passing variables in a php link to another page with auto scroll

Tags: php, html, variables, scroll

and thank you in advance for your great work here, i need help with some coding, i got a web page where i show a list of records of a mysql table, with a hyperlink when you click on it creates a variable like world.php?id=1&xx=1050&yy=300 so when the user clicks it takes him to next page and scroll down and up to the x and y it, works fine in web browsers but not working in mobiles. can you help me? the page world.php has 
,)">
this is the code i'm using

```
echo '<a href="world.php?xx='. $_SESSION['x'] .'&yy='. $_SESSION['y'] .'">';
echo '<b>';
echo $row['usuario_atacante'];
echo '</b>';
echo '</a>';
```

Comment: GET variables will not force the page to scroll on its own; there must be some JavaScript on `world.php` which handles the scrolling. Can you post the source of that particular code?

Comment: <script>

function ScrollByLeft() {
          window.scrollBy(<?php echo json_encode(($user_x-250)); ?>, <?php echo json_encode(($user_y-250)); ?>);

    }
    function ScrollByRight() {
          document.getElementById("mapa").scrollBy(-10, 0);
    }

   function ScrollLeft() {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
    }
    function ScrollRight() {
     window.scrollTo( <?php echo json_encode($xxx); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($yyy); ?> );
    }
    

</script>

Comment: thats all i got it does work when i use a computer but not when i use a mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this ?

```
<a href="world.php#row5">Row 5</a>
```

and make links in your world.php file.

```
<table>
<tr id="row1"><td><h2>Row 1</h2></td></tr>
<tr id="row2"><td><h2>Row 2</h2></td></tr>
<tr id="row3"><td><h2>Row 3</h2></td></tr>
<tr id="row4"><td><h2>Row 4</h2></td></tr>
<tr id="row5"><td><h2>Row 5</h2></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, this is a way to scroll to that row when i click on the link right? but i got this page like a map 1500x1500 and many objects around the page and when the user clicks on the link it scroll down or up to the x, y on the link and scroll to that other player icon.

Comment: How did you make your map ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a link like: world.php?x=345&y=200 to scroll to that location.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["x"]) && isset($_GET["y"])) { 

$x = $_GET["x"];
$y = $_GET["y"];

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>World Map</title>
<script>
  function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollTo(<?php echo $x.",".$y; ?>);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="scrollWin()">

<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e2/Geoffroy's_Cat.jpg" />

</body>
</html>
```

This is just a example to get you started.

Comment: Hi my map is made of smail images of grass then fill all the window so it looks like a big map then i have a DIV where i place width:1500 and Height:1500 then i have a php code to place every player in the x,y position which i get from the mysql table i already have, that is done ok, but when i come from another page using a link like world.php?id=1&x=345&y=200 then this link you scroll the world.php page to that specific x,y position, document.getElementById("map").scrollTo( <?php echo json_encode($xxx); ?>,<?php echo json_encode($yyy); ?> ); works only when i use computer browser not mobiles

Comment: But is the code that i posted above working on your mobile ?

Comment: Hello Neko It works fine, Now i got another question if you may help me is there a way to center the window to this x,y point if is posible?

Comment: if(isset($_GET["center"])) { $x = (3000 - 1280) / 2; $y = (2000 - 800) / 2; }

Comment: Just an example if your map is 3000 x 2000 and your screen size is 1280 x 800.